# Can organisms like Noctiluca be commercially exploited?

Tags: ethology, bioluminescence

Scientists think that Noctiluca flashes to startle or scare away its predators. The bioluminescence might also attract bigger predators to eat Noctiluca’s predators, just like a burglar alarm that alerts the police to come to someone’s house to catch a robber.
 It takes energy to make the chemicals that allow them to glow. It would be a waste of that energy to glow during the daytime
But the question is whether we can commercially exploit this for human welfare??

Answer (score 2):

Well, scientists have been developing [Bioluminescent Plants](https://www.dezeen.com/2014/01/13/worlds-first-glow-in-the-dark-plant-genetically-engineered/) to use as a future road light source. Also, there is a way that Bioluminecent algae can be used as [medicine.](http://mentalfloss.com/article/80813/7-ways-bioluminescence-has-revolutionized-medical-research)